# append draggable image to a div for print

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-draggable

I am using the code below to drag and scale some images. Also I am using the code below to print a specific div. All elements inside this div are print well, but when I am dragging the new images on it and trying to print... images doesn't show up.

I am using jQuery and jQuery-UI.

JavaScript:

Printing Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function PrintElem(elem)
    {
        Popup($(elem).html());
    }

    function Popup(data) 
    {
        var mywindow = window.open('', 'my div', 'height=800,width=1012');
        mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title>my div</title>');
        /*optional stylesheet*/ //mywindow.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css" />');
        mywindow.document.write('</head><body >');
        mywindow.document.write(data);
        mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');

        mywindow.print();
        mywindow.close();

        return true;
    }

</script>
```

jQuery drag and scale:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
window.zindex = 999;

    $(".dragger").resizable({handles: 'ne, se, sw, nw'});
    $(".dragger").parent().draggable({
        stack: "div"
    });
    $(".dragger").rotate({
        bind: {
            dblclick: function() {
                $(this).data('angle', $(this).data('angle')+90);
                var w = $(this).css('width');
                $(this).parent().rotate({ animateTo: $(this).data('angle')}).css({width: $(this).css('height'), height: w});

            }
        }
    });

});
</script>
```

Draggable images:

```
<div id="decorations" style="width:180px; height:770px; position:absolute;">

<div style="float:left; margin-left:5px; margin-top:5px;">
<img class="dragger" id="obj1" style="cursor: -webkit-grab;" src="objects/1.png" width="80" height="80">
</div>

<div style="float:left; margin-left:5px; margin-top:5px;">
<img class="dragger" id="obj2" style="cursor: -webkit-grab;" src="objects/2.png" width="80" height="80">
</div>

</div>
```

Printable div:

```
<div id="contentHolder" style="background-image:url(objects/papyrus.png); background-repeat:no-repeat;">

</div>
```

And the button for print:

```
<input type="button" value="Print Div" onclick="PrintElem('#contentHolder')" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The jQuery UI [draggable widget](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/) does not actually **append** the element being dragged into the element above which you visually drop it. Instead it just manipulates the CSS position properties of draggables and the position of those elements in `DOM` does not change on drop.

So `$(elem).html()` doesn't actually **contain** the elements you dropped into it.

For achieving this, you should initialize the drop target as a [droppable widget](http://jqueryui.com/droppable/), and manually append the draggable to the droppable on [`drop`](http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#event-drop) event. Something along:

```
$("#contentHolder").droppable({
  accept: "img.dragger",
  drop:function(event,ui){
    $(this).append(ui.draggable); // actually append the item on drop
  }
});
```